# Firebase Firestore DocumentReference in Typescript is not returning the document properties

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase Cloud Function that will write a Firestore document and then return the documents unique ID to a Flutter app. I'm using Typescript to write my functions.

This is the code that writes the document:

```
db.collection('devices').doc().set({"deviceId": userId},{merge: true})
    .then((docRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>) => {
        functions.logger.info(`Document path: ${docRef.path}`,{structuredData: true});
        functions.logger.info(`Document written with ID: ${docRef.id}`,{structuredData: true});
        response.status(200).send({"result":"success", "docId": docRef.id});
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
        functions.logger.error(error,{structuredData: true});
        response.status(200).send({"result":"error", "message": error.message});
    });
```

The `set` method returns a promise with a payload that should be of the type `DocumentReference` and contain the `id`.
The document is being written to `Firestore`, but it is not getting the values of the `DocumentReference` so I can send it back in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set()` method returns a [WriteResult](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/WriteResult.html) object that only has a `writeTime` property. It's `add()` method that returns a `DocumentReference` so try using that instead as shown below:

```
db.collection("devices").add({ deviceId: userId })
  .then((docRef) => {
    functions.logger.info(`Document written with ID: ${docRef.id}`,{structuredData: true});
  })
```

If you want to use `set()` then you'll have to store the document ID before itself like this:

```
const newDocRef = db.collection("devices").doc();

newDocRef.set({ deviceId: userId })
  .then(() => {
    functions.logger.info(`Document written with ID: ${newDocRef.id}`,{structuredData: true});
  })
```

Either ways, you don't need `{merge: true}` as they'll create a new document.